# Adding Big O notation Example

Tags: big-o, code-complexity

- t(n) = 1000n + 283n^2+4n^3

Why is the largest valid bound for t(n) n^4? When adding them up, don't you select the biggest between them, which is n^3?
I'm still new to this, thanks for helping out.

Comment: `O(n^4)` is not the largest bound, I think.  Actually, _any_ bound which is greater than or equal to `O(n^3)` is valid.  It doesn't make sense to speak of largest bound, but rather the tightest bound.

Comment: t is in O(n^3)     !!!!

Comment: `Why is the largest valid bound for t(n) n^4?` - quote the source for this (incorrect) statement.

Comment: I just asked my professor and O(n^4) is a valid bound because since it's Big O, anything that is asymptotically higher works, such as O(n^10000).

Answer (score 0):

```
t(n)  = 1000n + 283n^2 + 4n^3
     <= n*n + n * n^2 + 4n^3          ; for n >= 1000
      = n^2 + n^3 + 4n^3
     <= n^3 + n^3 + 4n^3              ; because n^2 <= n^3
      = 6n^3
      = O(n^3)
```